# Vb.net Inserting a row to DataGridView deletes the row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm currently working on an indexing tool and i count all the occurrences of old icons mapping to new icon (many old to one new)

I count all occurrences and get a result like this:

```
W0001_S32G2 1 O001_S32G1 3 -
W0001_S32G2 1 O001_S32G1 6 -
```

I would like after every same new icon add a total row:

```
W0001_S32G2 1 O001_S32G1 3 -
W0001_S32G2 1 O001_S32G1 6 -
     -      -     -      - 10
```

Where I count the number of occurrence of Old icons and New icon (once)
My count is currently correct but when I add the row at the given index it removes the current data instead of inserting it between actual rows:

```
For Each indi As String In cleanList
    Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim totnew As Integer = 0
    Dim totold As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
        If row.Cells("Name").Value = indi Then
           totnew = totnew + CInt(row.Cells("Nombre").Value)
           totold = totold + CInt(row.Cells("Nombre1").Value)
           indexes.Add(row.Index)
         End If
     Next
     DataGridView2.Rows.Insert(indexes.Last, New Object() {"-", "-", "-", "-", totnew + totold})
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since from what I saw online and that it wasn't possible to add in between lines I solved the problem by copying all the data to a list and then adding my new lines in the list with:

```
EndList.Insert(incre + i, MyHiera)
```

I then copied the list back to the DataGridView